# Has `ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest` disappeared?

Tags: docker, podman

I can no longer execute ...

```
$ podman pull ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest
```

I get this error:

```
Error: copying system image from manifest list: determining manifest MIME type for 
docker://ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest: reading manifest 
sha256:14c2e032457f617cf235fc51513d12ee735fd322687b321e2ad1f346062b66e3 in 
ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9: manifest unknown
```

I know centos7 is not long for this world but is the docker/podman container still available?

Comment: Hello, are you looking for `centos 7` image to be used on your container?

Comment: Based on this [Github package](https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild-containers/pkgs/container/centos-7.9), it is still "a live", even with it, I am getting the same error as yours.

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a problem we haven't figured out yet. The intention is to provide a container image that works on both x86_64 (`amd64`, so Intel + AMD 64-bit) and aarch64 (`arm64`, so ARM 64-bit), but the way that's been done is broken - see https://github.com/easybuilders/easybuild-containers/issues/21 .

As a workaround, you can use the correct image directly, for example:  `ghcr.io/easybuilders/centos-7.9:latest-amd64`